# Getting Heart rate through iOS

Tags: ios5, camera, heartbeat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect heart pulse rate without using any instrument in iOS sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125222/how-to-detect-heart-pulse-rate-without-using-any-instrument-in-ios-sdk)

I am trying to figure out a way to create an iOS app to measure Heart rate but I am unable to get a start on how to proceed with it.

I read that it could be possibly done using accelerometer or using the camera with the flash to see the blood flow( though I dont know how that works).

Would anyone be able to help me with this or point me at a right direction so that I would be able to figure out what to do?

Comment: The user's heart would have to be REALLY pumping to be discernable with the accelerometer... and how would you use the camera to capture something that's invisible below the skin? Include a knife so they can open an artery and count the spurts?

Comment: I've heard somebody doing it using the microphone

Comment: @MarcB I read that when the flash is turned on, the blood flow would be visible.. but I am unsure on how that works and hence I posted the question...

Comment: @MarcB Isnt that a little bit impolite? The method using the camera is based on an method that is actually widely used in hospitals. I reckon learner2010 can do this, after all there are apps doing this, and doing it well. http://mobihealthnews.com/13600/instant-heart-rate-app-passes-10m-users/

Comment: @learner2010 Hi, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the camera to measure pulses, and if the phone is held in such a way that there is a lot of light behind the finger that covers the lense then you can even do without flash, or use a phone that has the flash a bit further from the camera (as I do with my HTC HD).

The Instant HeartRate app for various phone has been tested properly (or so I read in an article) and works well, I've tested it on clients (I am a part time PT)- and compared to reagular heartrate monitors and actually found it to be more accurat as it measures faster before the heartrate drops.

As how to make the app, well I assume you will have to access the camera and detect changes in color and calculate the pulse based on the frequency of the change

I havent done this,- but logically it makes sense. I wish you the best of luck, and please share with us your solution :)

Comment: I have tried something-and detect the RGB color change if I place finger on camera lens.But from these changes how to detect the Heart rates,will it be accurate(somewhat) ?

Here is the link what I have tried - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/508075/SampleHeartRateApp.zip

Comment: @NithinMK: i have the same question as your comment above . So did you find the solution. If yes can you please share